# How to sort by column in descending order in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I tried `df.orderBy("col1").show(10)` but it sorted in ascending order. `df.sort("col1").show(10)` also sorts in ascending order. I looked on stackoverflow and the answers I found were all outdated or [referred to RDDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23838614/how-to-sort-an-rdd-in-scala-spark). I'd like to use the native dataframe in spark.

Comment: He means "df.sort("col1").show(10) also sorts in **ascending** order"

Comment: This solution worked perfectly for me : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38575271/5957143

Answer (score 115, accepted):

It's in [`org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@sort(sortCol:String,sortCols:String*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T]) for `sort` method:

```
df.sort($"col1", $"col2".desc)
```

Note `$` and `.desc` inside `sort` for the column to sort the results by.

Comment: `import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._` and `import sqlContext.implicits._` also get you a lot of nice functionality.

Comment: @Vedom: Shows a syntax error:
`df.sort($"Time1", $"Time2".desc)
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at the $ symbol

Comment: @kaks, need to import functions/implicits as described above to avoid that error

Answer (score 261):

You can also sort the column by importing the spark sql functions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.orderBy(asc("col1"))
```

Or

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.sort(desc("col1"))
```

**importing sqlContext.implicits._**

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
df.orderBy($"col1".desc)
```

Or

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
df.sort($"col1".desc)
```

Comment: also when you're ordering ascending by all columns, the `asc` keyword is not necessary: `..orderBy("col1", "col2")`.

Answer (score 76):

**PySpark only**

I came across this post when looking to do the same in PySpark. The easiest way is to just add the parameter ascending=False:

```
df.orderBy("col1", ascending=False).show(10)
```

Reference: http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.orderBy

Comment: The question is marked with a scala tag, but this answer is for python only as this syntax as well as a function signature are python-only.

Answer (score 21):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.desc

df.orderBy(desc("columnname1"),desc("columnname2"),asc("columnname3"))
```

Comment: This is a duplicate answer from the one 3 years earlier by @AmitDubey. should be removed in favor of that one.

Answer (score 8):

```
df.sort($"ColumnName".desc).show()
```

Answer (score 3):

In the case of Java:

If we use `DataFrames`, while applying joins (here Inner join), we can sort (in ASC) after selecting distinct elements in each DF as:

```
Dataset<Row> d1 = e_data.distinct().join(s_data.distinct(), "e_id").orderBy("salary");
```

where `e_id` is the column on which join is applied while sorted by salary in ASC.

Also, we can use Spark SQL as:

```
SQLContext sqlCtx = spark.sqlContext();
sqlCtx.sql("select * from global_temp.salary order by salary desc").show();
```

where

- spark  -> SparkSession
- salary -> GlobalTemp View.