# Accessing count column in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

```
code:

mydf = testDF.groupBy(testDF.word).count()
mydf.show()

output:

+-----------+-----+
|       word|count|
+-----------+-----+
|        she| 2208|
|    mothers|   93|
|       poet|   59|
|     moving|   18|
|     active|    6|
|       foot|  169|
```

I wanted to order this data frame based on word count in descending order.

```
code:

countDF = mydf.orderBy(mydf.count.desc())
countDF.show()

Error:

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'desc'
```

Please let me know on where am I going wrong.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30332619/how-to-sort-by-column-in-descending-order-in-spark-sql

Comment: @kgiou It is not a duplicate. Problem here is Python specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, dot notation is not the best method to access columns. While `DataFrame` provides column aware `__getattr__` you can encounter conflicts like this one, where name will resolve to a method (here [`DataFrame.count`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.count)) so instead it is better to use bracket notation:

```py
mydf.orderBy(mydf["count"].desc())
```

or `col` function:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

mydf.orderBy(col("count").desc())
```

to reference columns.

Comment: There is another option, `mydf.sort(-col("count"))`

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto `desc("count")` as well. `desc` methods are slightly more generic because don't require a type that supports `-`. Still, I think it is more about `getattr` mechanics than sorting itself.