# How to use orderby() with descending order in Spark window functions?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I need a window function that partitions by some keys (=column names), orders by another column name and returns the rows with top x ranks.

This works fine for ascending order:

```
def getTopX(df: DataFrame, top_x: String, top_key: String, top_value:String): DataFrame ={
    val top_keys: List[String] = top_key.split(", ").map(_.trim).toList
    val w = Window.partitionBy(top_keys(1),top_keys.drop(1):_*)
       .orderBy(top_value)
    val rankCondition = "rn < "+top_x.toString
    val dfTop = df.withColumn("rn",row_number().over(w))
      .where(rankCondition).drop("rn")
  return dfTop
}
```

But when I try to change it to `orderBy(desc(top_value))` or `orderBy(top_value.desc)` in line 4, I get a syntax error. What's the correct syntax here?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There are two versions of `orderBy`, one that works with strings and one that works with `Column` objects ([API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.WindowSpec)). Your code is using the first version, which does not allow for changing the sort order. You need to switch to the column version and then call the `desc` method, e.g., `myCol.desc`.

Now, we get into API design territory. The advantage of passing `Column` parameters is that you have a lot more flexibility, e.g., you can use expressions, etc. If you want to maintain an API that takes in a string as opposed to a `Column`, you need to convert the string to a column. There are a number of ways to do this and the easiest is to use `org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col(myColName)`.

Putting it all together, we get

```
.orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col(top_value).desc)
```

Comment: Is orderBy and sort same in dataset? Because both works perfect for me.


`org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col}`

`bhData.sort(col("count").desc)`

Comment: @vijayraj34 this question is about window functions and there is no `sort` or `sortBy` in `WindowSpec`. Therefore, I'll presume you are asking about dataset-level ordering. If you read the Spark codebase for `Dataset`, you'll see `def orderBy(sortExprs: Column*): Dataset[T] = sort(sortExprs : _*)`. In other words, `sort` is equivalent to `orderBy` at the dataset level.

Comment: I got an error when I didn't use parenthesis after the desc, not sure why. Once added, it works as I wanted it to, leaving me with `.orderBy(f.col('col_name_1'),f.col('date'), f.col('col_name_2').desc())`

Comment: @Anne you shouldn't have to use parentheses in Scala, which is the language tagged in the question, but you would have to use them in Python, which you seem to be using given the single quotes around your strings.

Comment: @Sim My bad, sorry! I was dabbling in PySpark, which is of course to no relevance to this thread.

Comment: @Anne I know this is a couple of years later but I'm glad you commented as I too was using PySpark and needed a way to get this working. Your solution worked for me so thanks!

Answer (score 13):

Say for example, if we need to order by a column called `Date` in descending order in the Window function, use the `$` symbol before the column name which will enable us to use the `asc` or `desc` syntax.

```
Window.orderBy($"Date".desc)
```

After specifying the column name in double quotes, give `.desc` which will sort in descending order.

Answer (score 1):

Column

```
col = new Column("ts")
col = col.desc()
WindowSpec w = Window.partitionBy("col1", "col2").orderBy(col)
```