# Scala Spark read last row under specific column only

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark

How can I modify the below code to only fetch the last row in the table, specifically the value under the `key` column? The reason is, it is a huge table and I need the last row, specifically the key value, to know how much it loaded thus far. I do not care about what other contents there are.

Line 1:

```
val df = spark.sqlContext.read.format("datasource").option("project", "character").option("apiKey", "xx").option("type", "tables").option("batchSize", "10000").option("database", "humans").option("table", "healthGamma").option("inferSchema", "true").option("inferSchemaLimit", "1").load()
```

Line 2:

```
df.createTempView("tables")
```

Line 3:

```
spark.sqlContext.sql("select * from tables").repartition(1).write.option("header","true").parquet("lifes_remaining")
```

Comment: what is the key column type? Do you just want the last key by ascending order?

Comment: @LiorChaga it is value, number in int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **orderBy** in a Dataframe like this, hope it helps:

```
df.orderBy($"value".desc).show(1)
```

Comment: adding it after line 2 wouldn't affect result of line 2. 
You could just do:
`df.orderBy($"value".desc).limit(1).write.option("header","true").parquet("lifes_remaining")`

Comment: @LiorChaga why do we order by `value` instead of `key` column. There are other values columns that also have `int` values

Comment: just copy pasted @YashShah reply. Yes, it should by by key column

Comment: I just gave an example writing “value” you should use “key”

Comment: @YashShah the list is already ordered in the database, I just need the value of the last row in the `key` column. I do not want to iterate over the table, I want it to just give the last row value , is that possible ?

Comment: @LiorChaga it seems like my question was not clear, can you kindly read the above

Comment: Oh, in that case, use `.option("table", "(select max(key) from healthGamma) as lastHealthGama")` when you read from the DB. This will return a dataframe with single column and single row, holding the last key.

Comment: @Matthew here we are just fetching  the last row by descending it and then ordering it, if you still are unsure what's happening you can look up this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32052881/6355940