# How to Sort DataFrame with my Comparator using Scala?

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to sort a DataFrame based on a column with my own comparator. It is possible to do this in Spark SQL?

For example, let's suppose that I have a DataFrame registred as Table "MyTable" with a column "Day" which its type is "string":

```
id  | Day  
--------------------
1   | Fri           
2   | Mon           
3   | Sat           
4   | Sun           
5   | Thu
```

And I want to execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY Day
```

I would like to order the column "Day" with my own comparator. I thought about using a UDF but I don't know if it is possible. Note that I really want to use my comparator in Sort/Order By operations. I don't want to convert String from column Day to Datetime or something similar.

Comment: Sorting using a general java comparator is not possible in spark. You need to define a sorting key (which type is ordered s.a. long, string, date...) and use orderBy for datasets or sortBy for RDDs. If you tell us about your specific logic, maybe we can think about a solution that would suit you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have to do 2 things: 
1) Use SQL queries like in this example; 
2) Sort a certain column with an operator when I have to execute an ORDER BY. 
Once it is not possible to use a general comparator in a UDF, do you recommend me another option? I thought about work with Spark Rules/Strategies to convert DF to RDD and use SortBy with my comparator. But I don't know exactly how to do this.

Comment: Actually, I was kind of wrong. It is possible to use Comparators (orderings in scala) with RDDs. I added a solution explaining how to do it. I also talk about alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SparkSQL, you do not have a choice and need to use `orderBy` with one or more column(s). With RDDs, you can use a custom java-like comparator if you feel like it. Indeed, here is the signature of the `sortBy` method of an `RDD` ([cf the scaladoc of Spark 2.4](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD@sortBy[K](f:T=%3EK,ascending:Boolean,numPartitions:Int)(implicitord:Ordering[K],implicitctag:scala.reflect.ClassTag[K]):org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[T])):

```
def sortBy[K](f: (T) ⇒ K, ascending: Boolean = true, numPartitions: Int = this.partitions.length)
    (implicit ord: Ordering[K], ctag: ClassTag[K]): RDD[T]
```

This means that you can provide an `Ordering` of your choice, which is exactly like a java `Comparator` (`Ordering` actually inherit from `Comparator`).

For simplicity, let's say I want to sort by absolute value of a column 'x' (this can be done without a comparator, but let's assume I need to use a comparator). I start by defining my comparator on rows:

```
class RowOrdering extends Ordering[Row] {
    def compare(x : Row, y : Row): Int = x.getAs[Int]("x").abs - y.getAs[Int]("x").abs
}
```

Now let's define data and sort it:

```
val df = Seq( (0, 1),(1, 2),(2, 4),(3, 7),(4, 1),(5, -1),(6, -2),
    (7, 5),(8, 5), (9, 0), (10, -9)).toDF("id", "x")
val rdd = df.rdd.sortBy(identity)(new RowOrdering(), scala.reflect.classTag[Row])
val sorted_df = spark.createDataFrame(rdd, df.schema)
sorted_df.show
+---+---+
| id|  x|
+---+---+
|  9|  0|
|  0|  1|
|  4|  1|
|  5| -1|
|  6| -2|
|  1|  2|
|  2|  4|
|  7|  5|
|  8|  5|
|  3|  7|
| 10| -9|
+---+---+
```

Another solution is to define an implicit ordering so that you don't need to provide it when sorting.

```
implicit val ord = new RowOrdering()
df.rdd.sortBy(identity)
```

Finally, note that `df.rdd.sortBy(_.getAs[Int]("x").abs)` would achive the same result. Also, you can use tuple ordering to do more complex things such as order by absolute values, and if equal, put the positive values first:

```
df.rdd.sortBy(x => (x.getAs[Int]("x").abs, - x.getAs[Int]("x"))) //RDD
df.orderBy(abs($"x"), - $"x") //dataframe
```

Comment: If I also want to use a comparator for GroupBy operations, the procedure is basically the same, right? Convert DataFrame to an RDD and use: groupBy[K](f: (T) ⇒ K, p: Partitioner)(implicit kt: ClassTag[K], ord: Ordering[K] = null): RDD[(K, Iterable[T])]

Comment: Never tried it but given the signature it seems possible. You will need to define a compatible partitioner though, that is one that always puts equal keys in the same partition.

Comment: I tried, you can make it work but it won't group keys that are not really equal, even if your ordering says they are and with a coherent partitioner. Your keys will be correctly sorted though. Depending on your use case, it may be enough.

Comment: I posted a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55147029/how-to-groupby-spark-dataframe-with-my-equality-comparators) for Group By example. It can help another developers. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey how do we do this in python. Please suggest a way to do it

Answer (score 1):

This is general way of doing it with dataframe

```
val df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM MyTable")

df.orderby("yourcolumn")
```

[orderby docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame.html#orderBy(org.apache.spark.sql.Column...))

---

If your ***data is less (seems like your have week names only)*** and then you can collect as list and use scala sortWith function

> The `sortWith` function Sorts this sequence according to a comparison
>   function. it takes a comparator function and sort according to it.you
>   can provide your own custom comparison function.

Different Example than yours :

```
scala> case class Emp(id: Int, name: String, salary: Double)
defined class Emp

scala> val emp1 = Emp(1, "james", 13000.00)
emp1: Emp = Emp(1,james,13000.0)

scala> val emp2 = Emp(2, "michael", 12000.00)
emp2: Emp = Emp(2,michael,12000.0)

scala> val emp3 = Emp(3, "Ram", 15000.00)
emp3: Emp = Emp(3,Ram,15000.0)

scala> val empList = List(emp1,emp2,emp3)
empList: List[Emp] = List(Emp(1,james,13000.0), Emp(2,michael,12000.0), Emp(3,Ram,15000.0))

// sort in descending order on the basis of salary.
scala> empList.sortWith(_.salary > _.salary)
```

Other options are : 
[How to sort an RDD in Scala Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23842386/647053)
In order to use this option you need to convert the data frame to PairedRDD and then do a sortbykey using the answer given there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helps me to better understand the concepts. 

As I said above, I need to do SQL queries like in the example that I presented. Do you know if is there any way to use Spark Rules/Spark Strategies to convert Spark Plans, convert DataFrame into DataSet/RDD in and use a comparator? It seems to me the only possible solution.

Comment: with plain sql its not possible